# Jquery Validate Plugin: no error messages from invalid textarea

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have this contact form that uses the [Jquery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) to do some quick user friendly validation before the form data is sent to a phpmailer script.

The name and email fields work as expected, however the comment textarea does not provide feedback and the form is allowed to submit even if parameters specified in "rules" are not met (i.e. required and minlength). Not sure what I've missed and would appreciate a look from fresh eyes.

```html
  <form class="cForm" id="commentForm" method="post" action="sanitizeandvalidate.php">
  <div id="feedback">
    <span></span>
  </div>

  <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
  <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder=" . . .">
  <div id="fnameError"></div>

  <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
  <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder=" . . .">
  <div id="lnameError"></div>

  <label id="lbl_email" for="email">Email</label>
  <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder=" . . .">
  <div id="emailError"></div>




  <p><label for="comment">Comment</label></p>      
  <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows=11 cols=60 placeholder=" Tell us whats on your mind."></textarea>
  <div id="commentError"></div>
  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
  <span id="loading"></span>

</form>
```

```js
$.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z\-.,()'"\s]+$/i.test(value);
});
$(function() {
  //form submit success/failure message 
  var feedback = $('#feedback'),
    feedbackDiv = feedback.find('span'),
   //ID of loading.svg
    loading = $('#loading'),
   //ID of Div that contains the form 
    tailbar = $('#tailbar');


  function showFeedback(message, attr) {
    feedbackDiv.text(message),
      feedbackDiv.attr('class', attr);
    feedbackDiv.delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
    feedbackDiv.delay(3005).removeAttr('style');
  }

  $("#commentForm").validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
      firstname: {
        required: true,
        lettersonly: true
      },
      lastname: {
        required: true,
        lettersonly: true
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      comment: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 10
      }
    },
    messages: {
      firstname: {
        required: ' First name is required',
        lettersonly: 'Letters or punctuation only please'
      },
      lastname: {
        required: ' Last name is required',
        lettersonly: ' Letters or punctuation only please'
      },
      email: {
        required: ' Please enter an email address',
        email: ' Not a <em>valid</em> email address'
      },
      comment: {
        required: ' A comment is required',
        minlength: ' Your comment must excede 10 characters'
      },
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if (element.attr('name') == 'comment')
        error.insertAfter('#commentError');
      else if (element.attr('name') == 'email')
        error.insertAfter('#emailError');
      else if (element.attr('name') == 'lastname')
        error.insertAfter('#lnameError');
      else if (element.attr('name') == 'firstname')
        error.insertAfter('#fnameError');
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      var options = {
        beforeSubmit: function() {
          loading.show();
        },
        success: function() {
          showFeedback('Thank you for your message, we will get back to you as soon as possible.', 'success');
          form.reset();
          loading.hide();
          tailbar.delay(4000).slideToggle('slow');
        },
        error: function() {
          showFeedback('Sorry there was an unexpected error and your message was not sent. Please try again later.', 'failure');
          loading.hide();
          form.reset();
        }
      };
      $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
    },
    invalidHandler: function() {
      showFeedback('One or more of the fields are invalid.', 'failure');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: My only thought is that i have to do something different to validate <textarea> tags? not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies I've realized my mistake. this code works correctly (I must of missed something on jsfiddle for not seeing it in the first place.) my issue lied in that i in my project I separated the  with it's parent .

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to validate different way for a text area. I guess the error text do exist in DOM. First of all, check if it exists in the DOM. It may be hidden by the position of the submit button. This is exactly the same code you have provided. Try running it here. It works as expected

```js
// Code goes here

$.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z\-.,()'"\s]+$/i.test(value);
});
$(function() {
  //form submit success/failure message 
  var feedback = $('#feedback'),
    feedbackDiv = feedback.find('span'),
   //ID of loading.svg
    loading = $('#loading'),
   //ID of Div that contains the form 
    tailbar = $('#tailbar');


  function showFeedback(message, attr) {
    feedbackDiv.text(message),
      feedbackDiv.attr('class', attr);
    feedbackDiv.delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
    feedbackDiv.delay(3005).removeAttr('style');
  }

  $("#commentForm").validate({
    debug: true,
    rules: {
      firstname: {
        required: true,
        lettersonly: true
      },
      lastname: {
        required: true,
        lettersonly: true
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      comment: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 10
      }
    },
    messages: {
      firstname: {
        required: ' First name is required',
        lettersonly: 'Letters or punctuation only please'
      },
      lastname: {
        required: ' Last name is required',
        lettersonly: ' Letters or punctuation only please'
      },
      email: {
        required: ' Please enter an email address',
        email: ' Not a <em>valid</em> email address'
      },
      comment: {
        required: ' A comment is required',
        minlength: ' Your comment must excede 10 characters'
      },
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      if (element.attr('name') == 'comment')
        error.insertAfter('#commentError');
      else if (element.attr('name') == 'email')
        error.insertAfter('#emailError');
      else if (element.attr('name') == 'lastname')
        error.insertAfter('#lnameError');
      else if (element.attr('name') == 'firstname')
        error.insertAfter('#fnameError');
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      var options = {
        beforeSubmit: function() {
          loading.show();
        },
        success: function() {
          showFeedback('Thank you for your message, we will get back to you as soon as possible.', 'success');
          form.reset();
          loading.hide();
          tailbar.delay(4000).slideToggle('slow');
        },
        error: function() {
          showFeedback('Sorry there was an unexpected error and your message was not sent. Please try again later.', 'failure');
          loading.hide();
          form.reset();
        }
      };
      $(form).ajaxSubmit(options);
    },
    invalidHandler: function() {
      showFeedback('One or more of the fields are invalid.', 'failure');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <form class="cForm" id="commentForm" method="post" action="sanitizeandvalidate.php">
    <div id="feedback">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder=" . . ." type="text" />
    <div id="fnameError"></div>
    <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
    <input id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder=" . . ." type="text" />
    <div id="lnameError"></div>
    <label id="lbl_email" for="email">Email</label>
    <input id="email" name="email" placeholder=" . . ." type="email" />
    <div id="emailError"></div>
    <p>
      <label for="comment">Comment</label>
    </p>
    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="11" cols="60" placeholder=" Tell us whats on your mind."></textarea>
    <div id="commentError"></div>
    <input class="submit" value="Submit" type="submit" />
    <span id="loading"></span>
  </form>
</body>
```